# Copy records of a person from one database to another database - Oracle and Java

Tags: java, oracle, migration

I have a requirement.  Let us assume a hotel management system where we have records like Booking, RoomType, User extra.

Assume the system is in production. I need to copy all the records that pertain to a booking to another environment like system test. This is to ensure that we are able to replicate the defect in system test environment. Many times we are unable to replicate the defect in system test, but the issue happens in prod. Since we do have access to prod, the idea is to write a batch which will take a parameter ( say a booking id) and copy all the records from all the associated tables to an xml or could be something.

We will take this xml as an input from run a batch in our system test environment, so that we replicate the same data in our environment.

Has anyone performed something similar? Do you have any better idea to perform what I intend to achieve?

P.S : Let's assume that my target and source database are oracle for now.

It is not possible for us to get us the whole db dump as the data is sensitive. We intend to take the records from the database and anonymize it.

Comment: just have your dba clone the DB. Whether it's an entire DB, or just a subset of data, they would be able to do that pretty fast

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to dump the whole database using the data pump functionality of oracle if available. That's what we do in order to debug problems without influencing the productive environment.

You can read up all about it and the requirments here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm

It's safe to use (for exporting productive environments) and very fast. Depending on your user rights you may need a DBA to help you out with that.

Comment: It is not possible for us to get us the whole db dump as the data is sensitive. We intend to take the records from the database and anonymize it. I should have mentioned this in my requirement.